# couchDb map/reduce min&max + other data

Tags: couchdb

I have a document list that consists of:

- time
- sessionId
- appv
- museum

I would like to use the couchDB map/reduce function to get the result:

```
key : sessionId, value : {begin : time, end: time, appv : appv, museum : museum}
```

for the begin value: the minimum time value.

for the end value: the maximum time value

Currently I can have the minimum and maximum value with this code:

MAP :

```
 function(doc) {
   if(doc.sessionId) {
    emit(doc.sessionId, [doc.time]) 
   }
 }
```

REDUCE :

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {

  if (rereduce) {
    return {
      'min': values.reduce(function(a, b) { return Math.min(a, b.min) }, Infinity),
      'max': values.reduce(function(a, b) { return Math.max(a, b.max) }, -Infinity),
    }
  } else {
    return {
      'min': Math.min.apply(null, values),
      'max': Math.max.apply(null, values),
    }
  }
}
```

RESULT :

```
{"rows":[
{"key":"fromDev1548326238156","value":{"min":2,"max":999}}
]}
```

And when I use this map function:

```
  function(doc) {
       if(doc.sessionId) {
        emit(doc.sessionId, [doc.time, doc.museum, doc.appv]) 
       }
     }
```

I can't find the reduce function that allows me to get the result I want

Can you help me?